# filter an arrayof objects for duplicates and add a count qty Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array with objects and I want to filter, out duplicates and increase the quantity.

this is what I am doing to remove duplicates:

```
curCart =[{sku:1, name:product1, qty:1 price:5},
{sku:1, name:product1, qty:1 price:5},
{sku:1, name:product1, qty:1 price:5},
{sku:2, name:product2, qty:1 price:10}]

[...new Map(curCart.map((item) => [item.sku, item])
            ).values(),
        ] // returns [{sku:1, name:product1, qty:1 price:5},{sku:2, name:product2, qty:1 price:10}]
```

the code I have works as expected just filtering out the duplicates how would I loop over it to increase the quantitys?

Comment: Code presented dos not return anything, as it has syntax errors. Make [mre] by using <> button in editor to greatly incise chances of you getting an answer.

Answer (score 3):

you can use array.reduce.. ex:

```js
const curCart = [
{sku:1, name:'product1', qty:1, price:5},
{sku:1, name:'product1', qty:1, price:5},
{sku:1, name:'product1', qty:1, price:5},
{sku:2, name:'product2', qty:1, price:10}
];

const x = curCart.reduce(function(acc, curVal, curIdx, arr) {
  const dupIdx = acc.findIndex(el => el.sku === curVal.sku);

  if(dupIdx >= 0) {
    acc[dupIdx].qty = acc[dupIdx].qty + curVal.qty;
  }
  else {
    acc.push(curVal);
  }
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(x);
```